# Make PivotTable name dynamic in vb code

Tags: pivot-table

In Excel 2010, I recorded a macro of steps to create mulitple pivot tables (some on different sheets). However, I am struggling to get the code to accept a "dynamic" PivotTable name. My code originally wanted to automatically assign the next PivotTable number. For example, "PivotTable23", "PivotTable24", etc. Since I never know what the next number will be in the workbook, I changed it to the following and of course it does not work (I am new to using vb code):

```
Sub TestContinueSD()
'
' TestContinueSD Macro
'

'

    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Stmt_Volumes!R1C1:R46154C42", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", TableName:=PivotTables(1) _
        , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).Name = "TOTAL"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TOTAL").PivotFields("desc")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TOTAL").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "TOTAL").PivotFields("id"), "Sum of id", xlSum
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TOTAL").PivotFields("Sum of id")
        .Caption = "Count of id"
        .Function = xlCount
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TOTAL").PivotFields("sfreq")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TOTAL").PivotFields("txt")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 14
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "TOTAL (ALL)"
    Range("A1:B1").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.Merge
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "SUMMARY"
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the name of the PivotTable by setting the appropriate parameter of the `CreatePivotTable` method call:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(...). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", TableName:="TOTAL" _
    , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839885%28v=office.15%29.aspx for details on the CreatePivotTable method.